# What is the relationship between LATE and TOT?

Tags: regression, experiment-design, causality, instrumental-variables

My understanding of LATE was that it was the effect of a treatment on individuals who were induced to be treated by the experiment.  That is, the effect on compliers.  My understanding of Treatment-on-the-treated (TOT) is that it is the effect of individuals who are in the treatment group (which can include both individuals who were induced to be treated, and always-takers who would have accepted the treatment regardless)

However, my notes say the opposite -- that TOT is a subset of LATE, and that LATE allows for the existence of treated individuals who would have been treated even in the absence of experiment.  But I don't really understand why one of them is capturing always-takers and the other isn't

What is the right way to think about this?

Comment: @Parseltongue Is TOT the same thing as ATET?

Comment: if ATET is average treatment effect on the treated-- yes, it sounds the same.

Comment: I would agree with your first interpretation! ToT/ATET is a larger set! Which notes do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing out the estimands may help. With $Y$ as the observed outcome, $A$ is the treatment of interest, $Z$ is the instrument, and $Y^a$ is the potential outcome under treatment plan $A=a$.

For the TOT (or average treatment effect in the treated, ATT), the estimand is
$$E[Y^{a=1} - Y^{a=0} |A=1]$$
For LATE
$$E[Y^{a=1} - Y^{a=0} | A^{z=1} = 1, A^{z=0}=0]$$
From this, we can see that the TOT is estimated in the population *all* treated ($A=1$) individuals, whereas LATE applies to a subset of the treated individuals in the population. More specifically, LATE applies only to compliers as defined by $Z$

Answer (score -1):

LATE is a subset of TOT....I quote from Mastering 'Metrics by Angrist and Pischke:

"Researchers and policy makers are sometimes interested in average causal effects for the **entire treated population, as well as in LATE**. This average causal effect is called the treatment effect on the treated (TOT for short)" (Chapter 3 Section 1)